# How can I get Facebook public pages Rating information

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need following things to be done in my website with the help of Facebook:-

1. The user will select any Restaurant/Business in my website.
2. According to its Facebook page my website will show Ratings related information like Average Ratings, No of Reviews, >4 star reviews, <2 star reviews.

How can I get those data from Facebook if the website needs to access all these public information without any Login or any other dependency.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs are not really clear on the permissions:

> A page access token is required to retrieve this data.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/ratings

As the call would be

```
GET /{page-id}/ratings
```

I tried it with one of my pages, and with the `hofbraeuhausmuenchen` page (https://www.facebook.com/hofbraeuhausmuenchen). Turns out that I can only retrieve the ratings for my page with my page's Access Token. For `hofbraeuhausmuenchen` I get an empty result. Considering that I'd say you'll have a hard time extracting the ratings of pages you don't own.

Comment: As per the documents provided on the Facebook-Graph API to get info about the page ratings I need to first get the access_token for that particular page. We can get aceess_token if we have the manage_pages permission. If I get manage_pages permission for the Facebook app which I have created will it be able to get rating information for all the public pages I don't own???

Comment: No, you won't, as I described, unless you get the `manage_pages` permissions from all the page owner of the pages you're interested in.